# window.postMessage not working in componentDidMount without setTimeOut in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on passing data between a react webpage and a react-native webview. I want to send a signal to the react-native webview on the mobile once the webpage has been loaded.

I wonder why on the react webpage, the `window.postMessage()` doesn't work unless it's used with `setTimeout`. There's no error at all in the console, but it has to be delayed for about 500 in order to work. Can anyone explain that? I prefer avoiding `setTimeout` because it feels unreliable.

```
@observer
class TalkToMobile extends React.Component {
    @observable message;
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    message ?
                        <Editor data={this.message}/>: null
                }
           </div>
        )
    }


    componentDidMount() {

        document.addEventListener('message', (e: any) => {
            if (e.data) {
                this.message = JSON.parse(e.data);
            }
        });

        let payload = {};
        payload.command = "giveMeData";
        window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(payload), "*")

        /*
        setTimeout(()=>{
            let payload = {};
            payload.command = "giveMeData";
            window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(payload), "*")
        }, 500);*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to wait for the webview to load before posting messages to it, so it makes sense to do it from within the webview `onLoad` callback. Try the following:

```js
...
onWebViewLoaded() {
  if (this.webview) {
    this.webview.postMessage('');
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <WebView
      ref={webview => { this.webview = webview }}
      source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/'}}
      onLoad={this.onWebViewLoaded}
    />
  )
}
...
```

If you want to post message from webview to the app, try handling it in `componentDidUpdate`. By the time it gets fired the DOM is loaded and there will be no need for `setTimeout`